# how can i wait for javascript return before executing the second part of hub method with SignalR?

Tags: methods, signalr

I have a problem in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project.
I use SignalR to create a turn-based game and in a hub event method OnConnected(), I call two separate methods to refresh my aspx with javascript code.

Here is my code :

```
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {

        // Demande les infos du joueur
        Send2();

        string clientId = GetClientId();
        string clientName = utilisateurlambda;

        if (Users.IndexOf(clientId) == -1)
        {
            Users.Add(clientId);
            UsersNames.Add(clientName);
        }

        // Send the current count of users
        Send1(Users.Count);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

So I want the Send2() method to finish refreshing my aspx page before the method Send1(Users.Count) is called.

Actually, Send1(Users.Count) is called before Send2 finish. Please help me !

Comment: Could the client call another server method once Send2 has completed on the client, which will prompt the server to do the remaining steps.

Comment: Thank you Ryan :) I followed your advice and it works ! I separated the code in both client and server sides by calling each other every time and it works. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing your aspx page will kill your SignalR connection assuming you are completely reloading the same page you are starting your SignalR connection from.

Secondly, the client will not receive any messages until `OnConnected` completes. Typically connection initialization logic, such as adding a client to a group, goes inside `OnConnected`, and you probably don't want to start processing messages until your connection is initialized.

If you don't want to call `Send1` until your page is refreshed, you should not call `Send1` in `OnConnected`. Instead, call `Send1` in another Hub method that you call from the client after the page refreshes.

Comment: Thank you halter. I made a mistake. I dont refress the aspx page, I am just updating it. So the signalR connection is not lost. I am just doing hub server and clients calls one by one to execute all my code one by one. Send2() update the aspx.page, which calls another hub server method, and this server method recalls another client hub method is recalled, until all my code is executed. And now it works !